# In POSIX, can a main(void) recover command line arguments?

Tags: c, posix, command-line-arguments

In C, is `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` really needed to receive program arguments? In other words, when defining the main function with the signature `int main(void)`, is it possible to recover the program arguments using only POSIX interfaces?

I feel like I'm missing something, seeing that:

- POSIX defines multiple interfaces to retrieve other process-specific information. For instance, there are interfaces for environment variables (arguably inherited from C99, but also extended with functions like `unsetenv()`) and host identification (`gethostid()`).
- Specific operating systems define "global" ways to retrieve the command line arguments. For instance, Windows supplies the `GetCommandLineW` and `CommandLineToArgvW` functions, and HP-UX supplies the global variables `__argc_value` and `__argv_value`. Linux has `/proc/self/cmdline`, which can be parsed into `argv` and `argc`.

Comment: I'd say it is implementation defined.

Comment: Consider a function `int f(void)`. How do you access any arguments you passed to the function from the caller?

Comment: Regarding Windows, note that Windows uses a [completely implementation-defined way of defining main](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which could explain the need to get command line arguments through separate non-standard API functions.

Comment: @Lundin: AFAIK there still is an underlying ("DOS") `main` which then calls this function. That would be fine as of the standard.

Comment: @Olaf Program invocation is an entirely separate concept from function invocation. The same argument could be posed for environment variables. I'm sure you've heard of the non-standard `int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])`.

Comment: @Olaf "Underlying DOS main" of the form `int main (void)` or similar, would be a console application, which yields a mandatory, cumbersome console window. To get rid of the console, you make a Windows application instead, where the point of entry is WinMain and no GUI exists apart from what you chose to create.

Comment: @Rhymoid: Well, it is **not**. `main` is basically a regular function. A typical implementation, however, does not start from `main`, but with some special non-standard code ("startup" code). This prepares the arguments to `main` and calls `main` finally. It also cleans up when `main` returns.

Comment: @Lundin: I had in mind the `main` does all this (possibly some startup-code is involved, too), then calls the windows application entry. However, I must confess, it has been quite a long time since I last had a look at some Windows code.

Comment: @Olaf: It's not much of a stretch to imagine that POSIX defines some global variables where you could find the same `argc` and `argv` that are passed to main.  Obviously the startup code has to get them in an implementation-dependent way, since it's part of the platform ABI.  On most (all?) POSIX platforms, the first instruction from the binary that was `execve()`ed is *not* the first instruction of `main()`.  The point you're arguing, that there's no other *POSIX standard* way to see your cmdline args, appears to be true, but Rhymoid's correct that it could have been like env vars.

Comment: You can use `asm`. It's C, though what you can put in it is implementation-defined and conditionally supported in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

POSIX specifications do not include functions that can retrieve command line arguments.   All of the specified functions require, essentially, `main()` to orchestrate passing `argc` and `argv` to be parsed.

POSIX specifications (IEEE 1003.1, 2013 edition - the current version as I write this) has a section describing the  command line syntax used by the Standard Utilities (which are described in the "Shell and Utilities" volume).     However, those utilities - naturally enough - would use POSIX functions, so would be implemented with a `main(argc, argv)` that calls them.